# Divs with transparent text in CSS?

Tags: css, html, masking

I’ve been asked to create a CSS (non-HTML5) based site that has a filled div with a cutout that shows an image underneath it.

[image: Text Cutout Example]

There are additional overlays and other images which makes using static images a pain. Plus, I suspect that I am going to need to be able to scale the background as the browser window changes size.

I realize that I can create an image of the GROW text and simply place it on top of the background image, but I would rather see if this effect can be accomplished “for real.”

This needs to work in IE8, 9, and FF 4. I can fallback to another effect for older browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Never seen this done with CSS before, I'd use an image with transparent text. You can still get it to scale with the background image.

Comment: Working with a designer can be fun but they really push it sometimes. Their favorite line is, "just use Flash."

Comment: What browsers must be supported?

Comment: the only thing I could think of is using masks...but it still is going to be a pain in the ass to line up

Comment: I agree with @Jleagle. If you wanted to generate the cut-out text image on the fly, you could use a server-side graphics program to create it, but that's a whole new topic...

Comment: You could use a limited gif/png that is transparent for the text and green for the bg, but clip it to the text or some other limited portion.  Then in css use the same color for the background of an element that will help format the position.  that way it can have a dynamically sized bg but retain the text transparent area for the text.

Comment: "This needs to work in IE8" = Then give up on the dream of an HTML5/CSS3 solution.

Comment: Or, an option which I forgot is to use a <canvas>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using two images without any holes or transparency. It's a hack but works in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

That affect can be achieved using [CSS 3 image masking](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/). However, at the moment, only webkit supports the property.  I would implement something like this, then use a fallback for other browsers until everybody catches up to speed.

As a side note:You can also increase the CSS adoption be using [ChromeFrame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/), or something similar

An Example from that link:

> SVG images can be used as masks. For example, a partially transparent
>   circle can be applied as a mask like so:
>
> ```
> <img src="kate.png" style="-webkit-mask-image: url(circle.svg)">
> ```
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

html5 or something like a gpd as php gui. But html5 doesnt work with ie8 or before, at least if the client doesnt have the chrome frame of google inc.

Comment: Yeah, html5 just doesn't have the adoption yet for me to be able to use it

Comment: What specifically in HTML5 would you use?

Comment: take this answer as out of date, it was from Sep 2011

Answer (score 0):

If you can play with mix-blend-mode property, there is simple solution that work on all modern browsers.

http://codepen.io/sajijohn/pen/OXEgkj

**HTML**

```
<h1>SUPER-FLY</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:900);
*{
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url(http://unsplash.it/3200/1600?image=973) no-repeat no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  /*/////////MAGIC//HERE////////*/
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
  /*////////////////////////////*/
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode